# Split String and then parse as decimal

Tags: string, split, numbers, decimal

I have the following text:

```
   3.024         2.184        5.0000
```

in a string variable

I then split that and try to parse the decimal numbers, here's my code:

```
string linea;
linea = "       3.024         2.184        5.0000";
string[] test = linea.Split(' ');
Decimal[] numbers = Array.ConvertAll(test, decimal.Parse);
```

Now, when I do the parse, I get this error:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: The split probably leaves you with a bunch of empty strings too, which when parsed will probably throw an error. Like this: ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "3.024", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "2.184", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "5.0000"]

Comment: Multiple spaces in `linea` is causing `Split()` to create more than 3 elements. Squeeze those multiple spaces into one and trim both sides before splitting them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the lead from @neouser99 and the comments, I came up with this

```
string linea;
linea = "       3.024         2.184        5.0000";
string[] test = Regex.Replace(linea.Trim(), @"\s+", ",").Split(',');
Decimal[] numbers = Array.ConvertAll(test, decimal.Parse);
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what language you're using, does it support regex split?

```
linea.Split('\s+');
```

**update**

Since learning it's C#, I'll just add the add'l info

```
string[] test = Regex.Split(linea, @"\s+");
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks, I'm using C#. I'll try your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Add a catch for empty " " values, skip them when you go to parse. Although, it may be preferable to eliminate them, in which case (assuming it's not a fix number of spaces between values) replace every double space with a space recursively until there are no double spaces in 'linea'.